# Getting data from both $_POST and $_GET

Tags: php, validation

What I'm trying to do is identify input entry points. Those being $_POST and $_GET. How can I get data from both simultaneously?

If I do the following:

```
foreach (array_merge($_POST, $_GET) as $entryPoint) {
    $data = $entryPoint;
}
```

or

```
$array = array($_POST, $_GET); foreach($array as $element){
        $data = entryPoint;
}
```

if there are duplicate keys in $_POST and $_GET, this will ignore the one in $_POST. And the following below is not functioning as well.

```
foreach ($_POST as $entryPoint) {
    $data = $entryPoint;
}

if (!isset($data)){
    foreach ($_GET as $entryPoint) {
        $data = $entryPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So you mean looping through $_REQUEST? That doesn't work. No data is found.

Comment: I want to detect whether a certain word is being passed through either $_POST or $_GET

Comment: How do you confirm what data is "found"? What are your input values? What output do you expect from this? What output do you actually get?

Comment: Well assuming I want to find whether the word "dog" has been passed through them, I aim to achieve something like this: `foreach ($array as $entryPoint) { $data = $entryPoint; }` and I then compare the $data var to find whether the word has been used.

Comment: Please: any time you say "doesn't work", or "not functioning" here, consider replacing that with a statement of what you expected to happen, exactly what happened instead, and, if possible, the code you used to discover that.

Comment: `foreach ($_REQUEST as $entryPoint) {
 $data = $entryPoint;
}

echo $data;` nothing shows up when let's say I send data through a parameter in the URL. Blank page.

Comment: You are aware that you're overwriting `$data` in every loop iteration, and at the end `$data` will only contain the last value, right? Since you're not showing what you're doing with `$data`, at the moment all one can say is *Yeah, that ain't gonna do nothin'.*

Comment: I just need to take whatever has been send through $_POST or $_GET and store it in a variable.

Comment: Here: `$_REQUEST`. That variable contains **everything** that's been sent. Since this may be more than one thing, it's an array of stuff.

Comment: So can you give me an example because so far I can't get it to work

Comment: Try `var_dump($_REQUEST)` on it.

Comment: Perhaps, I should've mentioned in OP but I need it as a string and imploding won't do. The above however outputs `array (size=2)
  'input' => string 'UNION SELECT' (length=12)
  'submit' => string 'Send' (length=4)`. I don't need the submit button as well.

Comment: So what exactly *do* you need?

Comment: To take whatever has been send through $_POST or $_GET and store it in a variable as a string.

Comment: ;_; Do you expect a particular *key*? Do you not know the key? Why do you not know the key? Will you get more than one thing? Do you need just one of those things or all together? If the latter, what's the logic for converting many things in an array to a string?

Answer (score 1):

Although not always available depending on your PHP configuration, there is a super global named `$_REQUEST` which may contain a combination of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`. To learn about the various caveats to their availability, start here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: In what configuration won't $_REQUEST be available?

Comment: @MattGibson http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: Ah, gotcha, so you can configure the content (though $_REQUEST will still always be available, though it could be empty, right?) And if there's nothing in $_REQUEST, then by definition there won't be anything in $_POST or $_GET, either...

Comment: @MattGibson Yea good point. It's not clear to me from the doc whether it will be unset, or just empty. I assumed when it said "Setting to '' will mean no superglobals are set" they were referring to `$_REQUEST` as well, but reading it again, seems likely contextually they are just referring to the other ones.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm reading it. But it took a few re-reads to figure that out :)